# R-object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, csv, error-handling, load

I tried to find something to this problem on the internet, but wasnt succesfull, thats why I am here now.

When trying to run this simple Code in R

```
data <- read.csv("heart.data.csv")

summary(data)
```

I get the following error message

> Error in object[[i]]: Object of type "closure" not subsettable

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: There is another error message after your first command.

Comment: There is a function called `data` in base R so you should not use it as the name of your own dataset. What happened here is that R tried to apply `summary` to the function `data` instead of the content of your csv-file. I bet your problem is solved if you just call your dataset `ds` or `df`.